# SQL with group count

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, distinct

This is simple table and I have issue with group count.

```
STUID      DEPT
100        Math
100        History
200        Math
200        History
```

This is my query

```
select count (distinct(STUID)), DEPT
from table
group by DEPT
```

and outcome count 2 for Math, 2 for History.
I need count without duplicate for STUID so the outcome look like

```
STUID    DEPT
1       Math
1       History
```

My goal is to count stuid ( no dup ) group by Dept

Comment: *count without duplicate* is 1 for all DEPTs. So what is there to count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need count without duplicate for STUID

You query does that already: it counts each `stuid` just once, even if it appears multiple times for a given department. For example, if you had the following dataset, you would still get the same result (that is, a count of two for each department:

```
STUID      DEPT
100        Math
100        History
200        Math
200        History
100        Math
100        History
200        Math
200        History
```

If you just want the distinct `dept` values, use `distinct` - we could add literal `1` to each row, but it wouldn't be very helfpul:

```
select distinct dept from mytable
```

Comment: so base on your sample , i like to see the query outcome group count 2 for math, 2 for history. My goal is to count stuid ( no dup ) group by Dept

Comment: @user13570703: as I said, this is what you original query does: `select dept, count(distinct stuid) cnt from mytable group by dept`

Comment: Sorry , you're right. My brain is gone today. Thank you